# ssd samsung Media_Wearout_Indicator

Tags: ssd, smart

I have 3 servers with debian 8.

I did a test with: `smartctl -a /dev/sda`

And on the newest server the result is (2 weeks):
[image]

And in the other 2 almost of the same date they have these:
[image]

As I have to read these values to know if the disks are OK ?, because I see the Media_Wearout_Indicator  very low (63%)

The model of the disks is: SAMSUNG MZ7LN512HMJP-00000

Thank you.

Comment: This data is not in a readable format, do something with it.

Comment: Sorry, now I put the info in image

Comment: You can (well, should, really) use the [code block feature](http://superuser.com/editing-help#code) for console output.

Comment: Of particular interest is that the second SSD has experienced almost ten times the I/O, so it goes without saying that it’s more worn down. // But, then again, it’s only a few megs, hm.

Answer (score 0):

The disks seems to be ok. In GUI version of smartctl (Disks in Linux) you should see if they are ok, there is separate column with "OK" text. Don't worry about this indicator.

You may be worried if the Reallocation Sector Count would be more than 0.

Comment: But then the Media Wear out Indicator indicator is not important? , I thought it was important.
Is a disk of a server.

Comment: Total_LBAs_Written, how does it translate to gigas?

Comment: Media Wear Out I would read as the less the better. It must be something about writes to the disk.

Comment: Total LBAs Written can be multiplied by 512 to give the bytes written value. But for disks with 4096 bytes sectors you may need to multiply by 4096.